# Observable array of draggable items and dropping values onto sortable list items

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I've been playing with Ryan Niemeyer's excellent [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) plugin and the draggable example in particular.

I'm looking to achieve two things:

1. Create an observable array of draggable items.
2. Rather than drag items into the sortable list, I want to drop dragged items onto items in the sortable list and replace their value.

In the below fiddle, I've begun the first objective but the `Text: name` binding doesn't work. I'd appreciate any guidance with this and the second objective.

http://jsfiddle.net/AC49j/125/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what your issues with the code are, works pretty well already :). I do think I see what your problem is with the text: name binding, I think the change below fixes it the way you want it:

```
<div id="draglist" data-bind="foreach: newTask">
    <div class="item" data-bind="draggable: $data"> // Changed from data-bind="draggable: name()"
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

$data in this case represents the whole task, while name() represents the ACTUAL (string) VALUE of the observable name-attribute of the task. It seems this change makes it function the way you want it to.

The second objective is less clear to me. Which items should be droppable onto which items? E.g. should items from the right container be droppable on items of the left container? Or should everything be able to drop on/replace everything else? What about sort, is that even still needed?

**jQuery droppable custom binding** (in response to comments below)

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.droppable = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var $element = $(element),
                options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

            $element.droppable(options.settings);

            if (!options.enable) {
                $element.droppable('disable');
            }

            // Handle disposal
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $element.droppable('destroy');
                $element = null;
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var $element = $(element),
                options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
                action = options.enable ? 'enable' : 'disable';

            $element.droppable(action);
        }
    };
```

To use it:

```
// HTML
<div data-bind="droppable: { settings: droppableSettings, enable: canDrop }"></div>

// JS (viewmodel)
var droppableSettings = {
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var dropTarget = ko.dataFor(this);
        // perform your replace logic
    },
    hoverClass: 'container-hover',
    over: function () {
        // Handle over-event from jQuery droppable
    },
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    // For more settings, see http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/
},
canDrop = ko.observable(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. `$data` has solved problem 1. :) Sorry for not being clear about problem 2. The items from the right should be droppable on the left and sort is still needed.

Comment: I think you will need the droppable plugin for that as well. I'm unsure whether it will place nice with sortable, but it seems to me you need to make the items in the left container droppable and accept (only) items from the right container. Then you can leverage the 'drop' event on the items in the left container to perform the actual replace. It seems that knockout-sortable itself does not have anything to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks again - I wasn't aware of a droppable plugin. Can you post a link?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/
I'll update my answer with a simple knockout custom binding I use in my own projects for jQuery droppables.

Comment: Thanks Hans, sorry for the late reply. I was struggling to implement your binding so I've set up a bounty rather than continuing to bother you. :)